# How to configure NgbDropdown to display the selected item from the dropdown

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

In [ng-bootstrap NgbDropdown](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown), how would you display the text of the selected button so that what ever item the user selects replaces the default text initially shown?

In the example below, the goal is to display whatever sorting option the user selects.

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">

  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="sortMenu" ngbDropdownToggle>Sort by...</button>

  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="sortMenu">
    <button class="dropdown-item">Year</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Title</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Author</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Demonstrated in [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MpzcXb?p=preview).

**Example Component:**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'dropdown-demo-sortby',
  template: `
    <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="sortMenu" ngbDropdownToggle>{{selectedSortOrder}}</button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="sortMenu">
        <button class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let sortOrder of sortOrders" (click)="ChangeSortOrder(sortOrder)" >{{sortOrder}}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class DropdownDemoSortby {

  sortOrders: string[] = ["Year", "Title", "Author"];
  selectedSortOrder: string = "Sort by...";

  ChangeSortOrder(newSortOrder: string) { 
    this.selectedSortOrder = newSortOrder;
  }

}
```

Comment: I can't comment directly to the solution you posted because I don't have enough reputation on this account yet... (if you accept my answer that will help).  But, you have your *ngFor in the wrong place, as that will duplicate the div tag too, when all you want to have multiple of are the buttons.   Also, you should have Angular bind to the click event using (click) on the button instead of HTML 'on-click' for your event. Finally, if you want to use an 'id' for each button, you should make them unique. Currently all your buttons will have the same id value because of the *ngFor.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by hooking into the on-click event of the selected button ( using the blur event doesn't work in Firefox) - [Plunkr demo](http://plnkr.co/5foGDLX7MadZ0pa32EVq)

The component:

```
export class NgbdDropdownBasic {
    displayMessage = "Sort by...";
    sortOptions = ["Balance", "Company", "Last Name"]

    changeMessage(selectedItem: string){
       this.displayMessage = "Sort by " + selectedItem;
     }
 }
```

The template with NgbDropdown:

```
 <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">

    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary"
            id="dropdownMenu1"
            ngbDropdownToggle >

    {{displayMessage}}

    </button>

    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="options" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
      <div *ngFor="let option of sortOptions">
        <button class="dropdown-item" 
                id="option" on-click="changeMessage(option)">{{option}}</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had struggled with `ngbDropdown`. And I saw this blog and assigned. But it didn't work.
After a while, I found a solution. Instead of `class="dropdown-menu"` I used `ngbDropdownMenu` directive. The code is the same as below.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
     selector: 'dropdown-demo-sortby',
     template: `
                <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
                   <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" ngbDropdownToggle> 
                      {{selectedSortOrder}}</button>
                   <div ngbDropdownMenu>
                        <button class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let sortOrder of 
                                sortOrders" (click)="ChangeSortOrder(sortOrder)" > 
                                {{sortOrder}}</button>
                   </div>
               </div>
             })
     export class DropdownDemoSortby {

             sortOrders: string[] = ["Year", "Title", "Author"];
             selectedSortOrder: string = "Sort by...";

             ChangeSortOrder(newSortOrder: string) { 
              this.selectedSortOrder = newSortOrder;
             }

     }
```

Thanks for your reading.