# NgbDropdown click event not working

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I know I am missing something small but have to ask because this just isnt working.  The click event for the button is not firing.  I have started with the [documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) and then moved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42170566/how-to-configure-ngbdropdown-to-display-the-selected-item-from-the-dropdown) copied this in to one of my pages.  When I add in the NgbdDropdownBasic module it breaks.  If I dont add that in they the css and button render correctly but the click event isnt firing.  Not sure what along the way I missed?

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'dropdown-demo-sortby',
template: `
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="sortMenu" ngbDropdownToggle>
   {{selectedSortOrder}}</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="sortMenu">
    <button class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let sortOrder of sortOrders" 
    (click)="ChangeSortOrder(sortOrder)" >{{sortOrder}}</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 `
 })
 export class DropdownDemoSortby {

 sortOrders: string[] = ["Year", "Title", "Author"];
 selectedSortOrder: string = "Sort by...";

  ChangeSortOrder(newSortOrder: string) { 
  this.selectedSortOrder = newSortOrder;
 }

}
```

I imported `NgbModule.forRoot()` in my app module.  Then in my component I've added

`import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgbdDropdownBasic } from './dropdown-basic';` <--getting compile error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a

```
ngbDropdownMenu
```

tag in your inner div. Should be:

```html
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="sortMenu" ngbDropdownToggle>
   {{selectedSortOrder}}</button>
  <!-- Missing tag added below -->
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="sortMenu" ngbDropdownMenu>
    <button class="dropdown-item" 
            *ngFor="let sortOrder of sortOrders" 
             (click)="ChangeSortOrder(sortOrder)">{{sortOrder}}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```