# Display filter based on dropdown selected value

Tags: typescript, filter, angular6

Am using angular6 reactive forms. It has 3 dropdowns in the form. whenever there is a value change in any of the dropdown, I need to display those selected values in "filter applied" column with close icon.
so if the close icon is clicked, the filter should hide and the corresponding dropdown should be resetted.

I was trying trying with pipe and pipetransform. But it turned out to be not useful in this case. Please let me know any ideal way to proceed this

**Expected result:**
[image]

Comment: Provide the Code that you have tried with sample data

Comment: am stuck with the way of implementation only. I was going through this PIPE https://angular.io/guide/pipes#!#custom-pipes. which seems to be out of context for the above

Comment: Post the code without pipe

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vmlafm?file=app/dropdown-basic.html

I just created this example in stackblitz. my real implementation was also based on ngbDropdown.

Comment: See this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/42172078/7124761

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a property for each fields, for example: `selectedDeliveryMethod`, `selectedAssesments`, `selectedAvailibity`, etc... and then use two way binding to set the `selected*` properties in function of the dropdown. To display it you can display it only when the value is not defined (`undefined`), and when you click on the close icon, you set the value to `undefined`, so it will disapear.

Example:

#### Component

```
@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent {
  public selectedItem: any;
  public itemArray: any = [
    "USA",
    "Canada",
    "France",
  ];

  public removeSelectedItem(): void {
    this.selectedItem = undefined;
  }
}
```

#### HTML

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
  <option *ngFor="let item of itemArray">{{ item }}</option>
</select>

Selected filter: 
<span *ngIf="selectedItem != undefined">
  {{ selectedItem }}
  <button (click)="removeSelectedItem()">Remove selected item</button>
</span>
```

There is a stackblitz to show you how it works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eytqnx

Another option would be to add the select item of any dropdown into an `Array` and then display it using the `*ngFor` directive with a custom template (text + close icon)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! Let me give a try with this approach